# Coded UI Tests Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I have a sample test project.  After I've recorded my test, and clicked "Generate Code", I get an error saying "The TopLevelWindow With Id was not found".  I have deleted the project, rebuilt the solution and created a new test project from scratch.

Does anyone know why I might be receiving this error?

Thanks.

Comment: When after are you getting the error?  when trying to re-play the test or when it is generating the UI map?  If it's during replay, is the window you are looking for open / does your test open to the window you are looking for?  Also, sometimes what coded UI generates is too specific and re-play will not work.  Please include the UI map generated and the test code that is failing.

Comment: I'm getting the error when trying to replay the test. As far as the window being open is concerned, it isn't but part of the test is opening up Internet Explorer from the start menu, and typing my localhost address into the address bar.  I'm going to add the code you asked for to the initial question.

Comment: You should directly launch the browser to the specified URL.  otherwise, you'll have to launch the browser to about:blank and use coded ui to enter the url which is outside the scope of what you should be testing (ie, you should not be testing that the user can enter an address into the browser address bar)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up "rightlicking in the UI map and clicking "Generate Code for Coded UI Test".  I'm having a bit of a differnt issue now, but I will create a new question for this.